# Significance of Class diagrams in c#

Tags: c#, uml, class-diagram

One of the interview which i recently attended asked about to write an ATM transaction class diagrams. I got stuck and wrote simple boxes with Login -> Check balance etc.. But do we have any standard method to write class diagrams?if so can any body write a class diagram for ATM transaction or any other activities. What is the significance of class diagrams and what is the difference between class diagrams and UML diagrams?

Comment: It appears to be a common case regarding any kind of UML's. A video, I've recently watched, was about exactly ATM transactions class diagrams. So, maybe, your employers expects you to have learnt the basics which are taught in the informatics colleges. If you simply google "ATM class diagram" and open Images, you will find pretty good examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class diagram is a type of UML diagram. It is one of the simplest structural diagrams in UML.
Please refer this for more info: http://creately.com/blog/diagrams/class-diagram-relationships/